# bootstrap list group must be over content of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap `list-group` to create a search box like `Google Search`;

I get a list from an Ajax and append it to my `list-group`.

When I `append` this list, all the content go down. I want that this list appears over all the content.

SOmeone can help me do that?

My Code:

```
<div class="list-group" id="ProcListaItem">
    <label>Credenciado Solicitante</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeCredenciado" placeholder="Credenciado">
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$.get('ajax/ajustecid/getProcedimentos.asp?NumAtend=' + xNumAtend)

.done(function (data) {
    if (data.status) {

        $.each(data.resultado, function (ResultadoItens, item) {$('#ProcListaItem').append('<li class="list-group-item" title="' + item.DesProcTab + '"><span class="badge">' + item.CodProcTab + '</span>' + item.DesProcTabLimit + '</li>')});

    }
    else {
        $('#ProcListaItem').append('<li class="list-group-item">Nothing Found</li>')
    }
})
```

[image: Bootstrap list-group]

Comment: Difficult to understand your question, if you could clarify with pictures or something that would be great.

Comment: I have add a picture. Note that when i append the childs `list-group-item` all the content above my Input goes down. I wish that all the childs be over the content above my search input. (just like google search box does).

Comment: Try to use bootstap `.dropdown` class with `.dropdown-menu` instead of `.list-group-item`. Then your result will be over content that is under input

Comment: Could you, please, provide a simple code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just added this CSS to my `list-group`:

```
style="position: absolute; z-index: 999;"
```